How can I understand these macro function final output?
I got a piece of code like this.
#define MAKE_SINGLETON_1(classname, traits)          \
        ;                                                   \
    protected:                                              \
        friend class base::Singleton<classname, traits>;    \
    private:                                                \
        classname(const classname&) = delete;               \
        classname& operator=(const classname) = delete;     \
    protected:                                              \
        classname();                                        \
        virtual ~classname();

#define MAKE_SINGLETON_2(classname)                   \
        ;                                                   \
    protected:                                              \
        friend class base::Singleton<classname>;            \
    private:                                                \
        classname(const classname&) = delete;               \
        classname& operator=(const classname) = delete;     \
    protected:                                              \
        classname();                                        \
        virtual ~classname();

// selector
#define MAKE_SINGLETON_X(x, A, B, FUNC, ...) FUNC

// default parameter
#define MAKE_SINGLETON(...)                                 \
            MAKE_SINGLETON_X(, ##__VA_ARGS__, MAKE_SINGLETON_1(__VA_ARGS__), MAKE_SINGLETON_2 (__VA_ARGS__))
}

In other classes, it is used like this
class CConnManager: public Singleton<CConnManager, Mutex>
{
    MAKE_SINGLETON( CConnManager, Mutex )
//other logic
}

I don't understand what MAKE_SINGLETON finally produces.
Is it MAKE_SINGLETON_2 that finally called?
Could anybody help me explain? Thank you very much.

Ah, that's a trick to overload macros based on their argument count! It will expand to MAKE_SINGLETON_1 since that's the one with two arguments.

@Violet I don't understand the //selector logic. Why FUNC is one of the param then it is also the token?

FUNC is just the name of the argument there. MAKE_SINGLETON_X expands to whatever its fourth argument is. The fourth argument will either be MAKE_SINGLETON_1(__VA_ARGS__) or MAKE_SINGLETON_2 (__VA_ARGS__) depending on how many arguments __VA_ARGS__ resolves to. So if you had two arguments, it would shift the rest of the arguments by one.

@Violet thank you for your answer. One last question, could you please explain the ##  in MAKE_SINGLETON_X? I still don't understand the difference between VA_ARGS and ##VA_ARGS

That's to handle the case where there are no arguments. It's not necessary in your example and is a GCC specific extension. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html

So this makes it easier to declare lots of singletons. There ought to be a law against that.  :-)
